# How can I touch a UIAlertView's 'OK' or 'Cancel' button using Frank?

Tags: iphone, ios, testing, cucumber, frank

I have tried a few different things including this:

```
 When /^I touch the alertview button marked "(.*?)"$/ do |alert_btn_name|
   touch "view: 'UIAlertButton' marked:'#{alert_btn_name}'"
 end
```

and

```
 When /^I touch the (\d*)(?:st|nd|rd|th)? alert view button$/ do |ordinal|
   ordinal = ordinal.to_i
   touch( "alertView threePartButton tag:#{ordinal}" )
 end
```

What is a good way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks good, is it not working?

You can also try to use the Frank predefined steps, and just do:

```
When I touch "Cancel"
Then I should not see an alert view
```

Or if you want the actual step for "When I touch ..", it would be:

```
When /^I touch "([^\"]*)"$/ do |mark|
      quote = get_selector_quote(mark)
      selector = "view marked:#{quote}#{mark}#{quote} first"
      if element_exists(selector)
         touch( selector )
      else
         raise "Could not touch [#{mark}], it does not exist."  
      end
      sleep 1
end
```

Comment: This method of locating views no longer seems to work with labels displayed on a `UIAlertController` on iOS10